# How do I turn comments into a chat room?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, chat

I'm not a moderator but I've been previously prompted to start a chat when there are a few comments in a row. I've seen some answers to this where users suggest that I start adding several comments in order to trigger the chat but (as you can see below) this is not working...

[image: screen shot]

Comment: it takes 3 back and forth, so 3 from you and 3 from him

Comment: Also he doesn't have enough rep to chat so you can't move it.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288572/162102

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) \[Linking this to the FAQ as [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/786798) explains the algorithm in the "Miscellaneous information" section]