# How to direct a discussion from comments into a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

We are discussing an issue on Buddhism SE site. Explaining something via comments is really hard, so is there a way to direct it in to a new chat room?

Comment: Is there something wrong with creating a chat room and posting a comment asking further discussion to be done in that chat room?

Comment: You can create a room, copy comments (one at a time), and leave a comment with the link, which is [a little cumbersome but can work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288572/162102).  (The link is to a feature request to make this easier.)